# HTML, CSS | Create a hidden shelf underneath modal

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

While improving my CSS skills, I got an idea based on a UX design I found.
In that UX design, there's a modal, that underneath it, there's a shelf, that opens up and contains extra data.

Now, I'm using [Mantine](https://mantine.dev) modals in my project (Mantine v4.2 & React v18), but I couldn't get the desired behavior and I want to create my component.

I'm not asking for the full implementation, because I want to achieve the goal myself, but I do need help with the positioning of the divs one under another:

Imagine that we have 2 divs inside the container div:

```
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
  </div>
  <div class="modal-shelf">
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, when the shelf is hidden, it needs to be behind the modal, centered vertically to the viewport, and right aligned to the edge of the modal,

[image: Shetch - Hidden Shelf]
But when it opens, it moves the modal to the left, so it can take the space, and center both modal and shelf.

[image]

Now, the limitation that I have is the fact that I don't know the height of the content of the modal itself.

**EDIT**: For simplicity, this is what I mean:

[image: Demo]

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap calls it an Offcanves
[Bootstrap Offcanves][1]
[1]: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/offcanvas/

You can check it to see how it works.

Comment: This is a complete different use case. Sidenav, or Offcanvas is starting from the side of the viewport, and not related to a specific div.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).